# google firestore auth exists rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does anyone have their heads around this auth business? I have nurses (users) and patients and I want to give the nurses permission on some patient records.

Now (discarding everything i know about relational databases) I've put permissions under each patient, where each permission has ID of the user/nurse

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: 
        if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/
          patients/89QL8XXXXFf/
          permissions/KZztXXXXXRf1)!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

..ok got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents{ 
          //define the database variable, use it later as $(database)
        match /patients/{patientId}{
            //define variable patientId, use later as $(patientId)
            allow read, write: 
              // if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents //WORKS
              //    /patients/$(patientId)
              //   /permissions/$(request.auth.uid))
              if get(/databases/$(database)/documents //WORKS
                /patients/$(patientId)
                /permissions/$(request.auth.uid)).data.write == true;
         //you have to get(...).data.myProperty 
    }
    // match /{document=**} {
    //  allow read,write: if false;
    // }
  }  
}
```